# How do I find the class of an airbnb listing?

Tags: python, html, class, web-scraping

I have very limited HTML knowledge but I do have some Python knowledge. I am trying to implement the code in this [article](https://smithio.medium.com/scraping-airbnb-website-with-python-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-8ec86e327b6c) and this [github repo](https://github.com/x-technology/airbnb-analytics/tree/main/Part%201%20-%20Web%20Scraping),

I know it's probably a stupid thing but I am having real trouble just finding the class in step 5 of the WebScraping_Session_I file. Can someone show me how to find it for a random listings search. The class names I find are nothing like the ones in the code and they don't work, and it doesn't let me go to the next steps after scraping the code to implement to ML algorithm :)

Any help would be appreciated!

If I'm unclear with anything, don't hesitate to ask!

What I tried:

I inspected the HTML code, selected a listing to inspect, tried the class in the area that was highlighted and it didn't work. Asked ChatGPT as to why, told me it was the wrong class but none of the classes suggested by ChatGPT have been right either.

Comment: How about you try to read a bit of selenium documentation? 
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/
Or you watch some YouTube tutorials and follows them a bit to get more familiar, e.g.: https://youtu.be/lvFAuUcowT4

Comment: Web pages tend to change a lot, in part because of webscraping. I'd reccomend you to use the inspector in your web browser to see what part of the page you're supposed to be scraping, and go from there

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen in the code and what I've understood, the code breaks when you do `soup.find_all('div', '_gig1e7')`.

Assuming you haven't changed any code, I'm going to guess there lies the problem.

Looking through the documentation of beautiful soup's [find_all()](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#find-all) we can see that the arguments are: name, [attrs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#attrs) and others (If you read the docs you can see it's just scrolling a bit).

Looking into attrs (where I think the problem lies) it says that those are the different css classes. So the line `soup.find_all('div', '_gig1e7')` is searching for the div class where there's a _gig1e7 text or id or some other kind of attribute.

Try removing the _gig1e7 part, and see if it works (even if it gives you more matches than expected), and then try to find how has the web changed now. Probably the class _gig1e7 does not exist anymore, and that's why it's not returning anything.